# Scenario generation for Value at risk: How to interpret the scenarios

Tags: value-at-risk, scenario-analysis

This is a a simple and rather pratical approach and not theoretical. Let's assumes I have generated **250 scenarios** for a given fixed portfolio. Hence we assume that **the asset returns can result in 250 returns and each of them are equally probable**

How would you **interpret the scenarios in terms of value at risk?**. Say you want 10% VaR. Can you simply call the 25th worst scenario as your 10% VaR. What is my 1% var then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your 25th-worst scenario of 250 cases would be your 10% VaR. For your 1% VaR, as it doesn’t rest directly on a known point, you’d choose some function (cubic splines are popular) to approximate the curve, and interpolate.